# Http error 301 when reading website with asio/boost

Tags: c++, sockets, http, https, boost-asio

I would like to get the source html code of a website in C++.
I tried with `libcurl` and `curlpp` but I don't succeed to link and build the libs...

So, I found a sample code in the boost website for reading websites.

I tried, but I have the 301 error code (Moved Permanently).
If I go on my website ( https://www.fdj.fr/jeux/jeux-de-tirage/keno/resultats ) I have no problem, and the website appear to be OK.

Anyone have some ideas ?

**Here is my code:**

```
std::string strHost= "fdj.fr";
std::string strUrlPath = "https://www.fdj.fr/jeux/jeux-de-tirage/keno/resultats";
try
{
    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    // Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(strHost, "http");
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    tcp::resolver::iterator end;

    // Try each endpoint until we successfully establish a connection.
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
    while (error && endpoint_iterator != end)
    {
        socket.close();
        socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
    }
    if (error)
        throw boost::system::system_error(error);

    // Form the request. We specify the "Connection: close" header so that the
    // server will close the socket after transmitting the response. This will
    // allow us to treat all data up until the EOF as the content.
    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream request_stream(&request);
    request_stream << "GET " << strUrlPath << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    request_stream << "Host: " << strHost << "\r\n";
    request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    // Send the request.
    boost::asio::write(socket, request);

    // Read the response status line.
    boost::asio::streambuf response;
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n");

    // Check that response is OK.
    std::istream response_stream(&response);
    std::string http_version;
    response_stream >> http_version;
    unsigned int status_code;
    response_stream >> status_code;
    std::string status_message;
    std::getline(response_stream, status_message);
    if (!response_stream || http_version.substr(0, 5) != "HTTP/")
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid response\n";
        //return 1;
    }
    if (status_code != 200)
    {
        std::cout << "Response returned with status code " << status_code << "\n";
        //return 1;
    }

    // Read the response headers, which are terminated by a blank line.
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n\r\n");

    // Process the response headers.
    std::string header;
    while (std::getline(response_stream, header) && header != "\r")
        std::cout << header << "\n";
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Write whatever content we already have to output.
    if (response.size() > 0)
        std::cout << &response;

    // Read until EOF, writing data to output as we go.
    while (boost::asio::read(socket, response,
        boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error))
        std::cout << &response;
    if (error != boost::asio::error::eof)
        throw boost::system::system_error(error);
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: This is not realy problem... 301 contains header with another url to move to ([see][1]). since `boost::asio` is a low-level lib, you need implement it by yourself. mean: check if the HTTP status code is 3xx - then extract the url in `Location` header and move to him.

Comment: AAAok :) Thanks a lot for the answers ! Have you an idea how doing this with asio ?

Comment: I tested my request in fiddler ( using copy/paste ). All is ok in fiddler ( return code : 200 / accepted). So it's a boost configuration problem no ? But, why ?

Comment: I've checked the request with `tamper data` and i've got `304`. Your page may contents multyple requests.

Comment: The page is https, is this the problem ? how solved it ?